# how to get the hidden input value from the previous div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to get the hidden input value by clicking the text "upload profile photo". I am very new to these things.

```
          <div>
            <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $list['profilePitcureID'];?>'
          name="profilePitcureID" id="profilePitcureID<?php echo $j; ?>" 
              class="profilePitcureID" /></div>
           <div id="meTwo" class="styleall" style=" cursor:pointer;font-family:Verdana, 
         Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:9px;">Click Here To Upload Profile Photo</div>
```

Comment: Your going to need include a little more explanation that what you have ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
$('#meTwo').prev('div').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#meTwo').click(function(){
   alert( $(this).prev().find('input.profilePitcureID').val() );
   // or
   alert( $(this).prev().find('input[name="profilePitcureID"]').val() );
});
```

Not sure if this is what you want but it should work.

You maybe want to change `Pitcure` to `Picture` as well.

Comment: I am getting alert as "uddefined"

Comment: @Mansoor works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/dzzk9/ Maybe it's because of Pitcure-Picture mismatch?